# msi installer is not working with apache commons exec throws exit code 1639

Tags: java, windows, windows-installer, processbuilder, apache-commons-exec

I am trying to install a software with .msi file and it is working fine when I try in the Windows command prompt. But the same is not working in apache commons exec. When I run thru apache commons exec, it says exit code 1639 and the product is not getting installed.

Command prompt code:

```
msiexec /i "C:\Automation\Products\product_name.msi" /passive INSTALLDIR="C:\Program Files\product_name" PROCESSINGTEMPFOLDER="C:\ProgramData\Auto\Temp" SERVICEUSER="user1" SERVICEDOMAIN="abc.groupcom.net" SERVICEPASS="samplepwd" /lv "C:\Automation\Products\Install.log"
```

Apache Commons exec code:

```
log.info("Executing install command...");
String command = "msiexec /i \"C:\\Automation\\Products\\product_name.msi\" /passive INSTALLDIR=\"C:\\Program Files\\product_name\" PROCESSINGTEMPFOLDER=\"C:\\ProgramData\\Auto\\Temp\" SERVICEUSER=\"user1\" SERVICEDOMAIN=\"abc.groupcom.net\" SERVICEPASS=\"samplepwd\" /lv \"C:\\Automation\\Products\\Install.log\"";
CommandLine cmdLine = CommandLine.parse("cmd /c "+command);
DefaultExecutor executor = new DefaultExecutor();
executor.setExitValue(0);
int exitValue = executor.execute(cmdLine);
if(exitValue != 0) {
    throw new Exception("Error while executing the command..."+command+"::::Exit Value: "+exitValue);
}
```

I have used java ProcessBuilder and java Process as well, both are giving the same output. But it is working fine and the product gets installed via Command Prompt.

In order to avoid the UAC popup, I run my executable jar file thru Task Scheduler with Highest Priviledges.

Here is a working .exe file command from apache commons exec which is an exe file, but the same is not working for .msi files.

```
"C:\Automation\Products\product_name.exe" /i /ComponentArgs "*":"/qn /norestart"
```

Kindly help me to go thru this error.

**EDIT:** Below code also did not worked.

```
log.info("Executing install command...");
String command = "msiexec";
String args = "/i \"C:\\Automation\\Products\\product_name.msi\" /passive INSTALLDIR=\"C:\\Program Files\\product_name\" PROCESSINGTEMPFOLDER=\"C:\\ProgramData\\Auto\\Temp\" SERVICEUSER=\"user1\" SERVICEDOMAIN=\"abc.groupcom.net\" SERVICEPASS=\"samplepwd\" /lv \"C:\\Automation\\Products\\Install.log\"";
CommandLine cmdLine = new CommandLine(command);
cmdLine.addArguments(args);
DefaultExecutor executor = new DefaultExecutor();
executor.setExitValue(0);
int exitValue = executor.execute(cmdLine);
if(exitValue != 0) {
    throw new Exception("Error while executing the command..."+command+"::::Exit Value: "+exitValue);
}
```

Comment: I dont think your Java code will compile...

Comment: I dont see any errors while converting to executable jar from eclipse. Then only i am running in remote windows with simple java -jar.

Comment: The line `String command = msiexec ...` is not valid Java code.

Comment: Missed escape chars in question, Corrected it now @MarkRotteveel, in the above code.